# how to get reply message on disocrd.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

here is an example: someone send message that name `A`
and someone is reply to `A`. (this message is `B`) 
how can I get `A` from `B`?

does `message` have `reply` variable?

I'm useing discord.py and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute [`reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reference)

> The message that this message references. This is only applicable to
> messages of type [MessageType.pins_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType.pins_add), crossposted messages created by
> a followed channel integration, or **message replies**.

```
message.reference
```

and it returns the *message reference* `A` from `B` where `message` is `B`. After that, you can get the message using `cached_message`  or use `client.get_guild().get_channel().fetch_message(id)` stuff to get the message object.